# My App is working in Emulator but NOT in real device

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio 1.2.2 version. I have created my  android App in API 18 version from the start of developing.In my app Google map plays important role.

In my SDK Manager , they is no option to download the API level 17 & 18 for Google APIs x86. So I downloaded Google APIs 19 (x86) version. It is working perfectly in Emulator but not in Lallipop 5 version real device.

My app build grade:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bharat.plantnow"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    // multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

}

Comment: What is not working? Any error message?

Comment: connect the phone to pc, open the Monitor, filter the output to your app only and give us error it throws.

Comment: How are you installing app to the phone?

Comment: are  you not able to connect your device to studio r not able run your app in device ?

Comment: Did you enabled your device Dev Mode ?

Comment: Yes. I have generated signed APK and installed my app in Mobile. My app working perfectly for many activities but on Map activity I could able to see Map. i.e Its showing white back-screen with my current location button, zoom button and Google logo at left bottom of my fragment.

Comment: How come I am not able to find Google APIs x86 17 & 18 version in my SDK manager?

Answer (score 0):

The `GoogleMap` could not show because you when you use Emulator you have one build and when generation .apk file you have another build version.
Check out docs: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide